# Akka children restart policy

Tags: akka, actor

Reading #Akka Concurrency. I'm a little bit screwed-up.
If i don't manage children restart during parent restart, Derek states that there is no way to escape for children. The children will die or their state will be completely wiped out.
The question is what exactly will happen with children if not restart them during parent restart
One can do that by overwrite preRestart and postRestart methods simply skip stop in first and skip start in second

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop child-actors from being terminated when their parent dies, simply override the `preRestart` method **without** delegating to `super.preRestart` - the logic of terminating children is in that method in the `Actor` class.

This is explained in detail in the [akka docs section on "Supervision - What restarting means"](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/general/supervision.html#What_Restarting_Means)

Comment: i'm not sure that super.preStart preserves logic for terminating. It's actually starting children logic there. I know how to change default behavior. The question is actually what would happen if i skip children stop-start logic to nothing? what mean state will be wiped out? And my assumption that in case of skipping restarting children the original children's ActorRef will remain the same.

Comment: I mean `super.preRestart` of course, sorry for the typo